# undefined is not a function (evaluating '_reactNativeNavigation2.default.startTabBasedApp') startTabs StartMainTabs.js

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native, I just follow react native navigation official docs and try to use Navigation's startTabBasedApp. When I try to click on  Button from the main page to redirect the actual startTabBasedApp page shows error: undefined is not a function (evaluating '_reactNativeNavigation2.default.startTabBasedApp'). how can i resolve this error..

undefined is not a function (evaluating '_reactNativeNavigation2.default.startTabBasedApp') startTabs StartMainTabs.js How to resolve this error...[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because `Navigation.startTabBasedApp()` is no longer supported in v2 of react-native-navigation, so that could be the problem.

If you want to create a button for navigation, simply just follow like this:

```
import { Navigation } from "react-native-navigation";
import React,{ Component } from "react";
import { View, Button, Text } from "react-native"; 

class YourClass extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        Navigation.events().bindComponent(this);
    }

    navigationButtonPressed({ buttonId }) {
         //page that you wish to navigate 
    }

    render() {
         return (
               <View> 
                    <Button title="Navigate" onPress= {this.navigationButtonPressed("navigate")} />
               </View>
         )
    }
}
```

Base on the v2 docs, you can read it here, also guide for installation, usage and many more: 
https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/v2/#/

Happy coding !!